# Expo bare workflow, my app name for google and facebook sign in is "ios", not my app name

Tags: react-native, expo

I recently ejected my Expo React Native to the bare workflow. I'm using both Google `expo-google-sign-in` and Facebook `expo-facebook` sign in.

When you press the sign in button, an alert opens asking user if they want to use the service to sign in. In the alert it asks if "ios" can sign in. Can I use my app name instead? Where is that setting?

Note: This used to correctly be my app name before I ejected to the bare workflow.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Found it.

In xcode, it's Targets > Build Settings > Packaging > Product Name

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the "Display Name" Field Under "General" tab and FacebookDisplayName under info.plist in Xcode

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/